# Initializing base class with parameters generated by derived [C++]

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have a situation where I have some base class Base, from this class i derive DerivedA and DerivedB. Lets assume that the c'tor for Base looks like this:

```
Base(int a) : m_a(a) {}
```

now the problem is, that class DerivedA and DerivedB each use some algorithm to determine said "a", so doing `DerivedA() : Base(a)` is impossible, as a is being generated in the constructors body.

What solutions are there for such problem?

Comment: @Angew i just noticed that, then i have no solution for this

Answer (score 4):

Half constructing an object is always a bad idea. either you don't construct it either you fully construct it.

In you case the best solution is to use a free function

```
int complexCalculation(int a){...}
DerivedA():Base(complexCalculation(a))
{

}
```

Or you  can choose to use a private (or protected) static function

```
struct DerivedA{
DerivedA():Base(complexCalculation(a))
{

}
private:
static int complexCalculation(int a){...}
};
```

Comment: Why not a private (or protected) static function?

Comment: Because I assumed the computation could have been shared. But a private (or protected) static function would also be good

Answer (score 0):

You can create a private static function to initialize `a`

```
class DerivedA : public Base{
public:
  DerivedA() : Base(compute_a())
  {
  }
private:
  static int compute_a() {
    //...
  }
};
```

If possible, you can also convert `Base` to a template and make use of the [Curiously recurring template pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern).

```
template<typename Sub>
struct Base {
  int a;
  Base() : a(Sub::compute_a()) {}
};

struct DerivedA : Base <DerivedA> {
  static int compute_a() {
    //...
  }
}
```